# Rails model to pull data from REST api and save to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I'm making an app that needs to make an API request every 15 mins, put that data into a database, and put then load the data into highcharts objects.

How do I generate a model that will have these values that will have corresponding table columns:
id, calls_offered, calls_handled, timestamp

Additionally how do I access that data to dynamically update the charts I have created?

Bonus question: will that automatically pass over to Heroku when I deploy to it?

Comment: open any rails beginners tutorial and in 20 minutes you will know how to generate a model with corresponding table with needed fields, how to update the table's rows etc

Comment: Once I create that, should I have the API request in a controller or within the model?

Comment: this would not matter very much - it could be done from model, service, controller - whatever fits your needs/design most.